# Custom RowGroupHeader?

Tags: datagrid, coding-style, silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to customize the row group header in a datagrid ?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/summary-row-in-datagrid/

Even if you're not looking for the summary information, having the ability to set a custom value for the group name is helpful in a number of situations.